# An unidentified condition body - please help

Tags: apex, trigger

I don't understand how this piece of code works:

```
for (ServiceReport rep : trigger.new) {
        if (((Id)rep.ParentId).getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'ServiceAppointment') {
            // some logic here
        }
    }
```

Why is there (Id) before rep.ParentId and why are there parentheses like that?

```
((Id)rep.ParentId)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of `((Id)rep.ParentId)` is just overly defensive coding and can be readily replaced by `rep.ParentId`. It would be necessary to cast the value if you retrieved the field dynamically, as `SObject.get` returns `Object`.

Answer (score 3):

To supplement Adrian's answer, the `.` operator is of higher precedence (in [Java](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/%7Eguvenir/courses/CS101/op_precedence.html) and probably copied in Apex) than the `(type)` cast operator. So without those braces the `.` operator would be applied before the cast is applied. So it is quite idiomatic to have:

```
((TypeToCastTo) referenceToCast)
```

in code where the cast is needed.

(Casting is "I know more about the type of the reference than you do compiler so don't complain at compile time; if I've goofed the runtime system can complain instead".)

Comment: Hey Keith, thanks for the brilliant answer. Could you tell me why it would be a problem if the . operator was applied before the cast was applied? Cheers

Comment: Hi @DevelBase2, In this case the cast isn't needed, but if `ParentId` was just a string the `getSObjectType()` method would not be available and you'd get a compile error. Best to use the correct explicit types and only use casts in specific circumstances.

Comment: Thanks alot Keith